# Unknown token: IDENT , when decoding/parsing terraform file

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, terraform

I am parsing main.tf file , so that I can use the arguments passed into the module in my go lang program.

**Terraform 0.13 ( main.tf )**

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket                 = "bucket"
    key                    = "c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0.tfstate"
    region                 = "us-west-2"
    dynamodb_table         = "terraform-lock"
    skip_region_validation = true
  }
}

provider "null" {
  version = "2.1"
}

provider "random" {
  version = "2.3"
}

provider "template" {
  version = "2.1"
}

provider "archive" {
  version = "1.3"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "<= 4.0"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

output "aws_vpc_main" {
  value = module.dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network.vpc_id
}

module "dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network" {
  source        = "gitsource"
  cidr          = "10.0.0.0/16"
  cluster_id    = "c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0"
  env           = "dev"
  owner         = "me"
  region        = "us-west-2"
  super_cluster = "dev"
  platform_api  = "api"
  proj          = "this"
}
```

From the above main.tf file, I would like to parse various arguments ( i.e env, owner, region,cidr etc etc ) that is passed on to the modules.

I am using below go program to try to do some parsing going.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl"
)

func main() {

    FileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile("main.tf") // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    
    var out interface{}
    FileContentString := string(FileContent) // convert content to a 'string'
    
    err = hcl.Decode(&out, FileContentString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)

}
```

However above program is erroring out with the following error message - **`At 33:11: Unknown token: 33:11 IDENT module.dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network.vpc_id`**

If I change the interpolation syntax on the above main.tf file to match with terraform 0.11 and earlier, the program main.go just works fine.

**Terraform 0.11 ( main.tf )**

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket                 = "bucket"
    key                    = "c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0.tfstate"
    region                 = "us-west-2"
    dynamodb_table         = "terraform-lock"
    skip_region_validation = true
  }
}

provider "null" {
  version = "2.1"
}

provider "random" {
  version = "2.3"
}

provider "template" {
  version = "2.1"
}

provider "archive" {
  version = "1.3"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "<= 4.0"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

output "aws_vpc_main" {
  value = "${module.dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network.vpc_id}"
}

module "dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network" {
  source        = "gitsource"
  cidr          = "10.0.0.0/16"
  cluster_id    = "c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0"
  env           = "dev"
  owner         = "me"
  region        = "us-west-2"
  super_cluster = "dev"
  platform_api  = "api"
  proj          = "virt"
}
```

main.go program output

```
map[module:[map[dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network:[map[cidr:10.0.0.0/16 cluster_id:c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0 env:dev owner:me platform_api:api proj:virt region:us-west-2 source:gitsource super_cluster:dev]]]] output:[map[aws_vpc_main:[map[value:${module.dev-c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0-Network.vpc_id}]]]] provider:[map[null:[map[version:2.1]]] map[random:[map[version:2.3]]] map[template:[map[version:2.1]]] map[archive:[map[version:1.3]]] map[aws:[map[region:us-west-2 version:<= 4.0]]]] terraform:[map[backend:[map[s3:[map[bucket:bucket dynamodb_table:terraform-lock key:c2an8q6a0brja8jaq3k0.tfstate region:us-west-2 skip_region_validation:true]]]]]]]
```

Which, I can parse later on with various methods.

I am just out of ideas as to why its not working with the latest terraform version configuration.

Thank you.

EDIT

I just want to update this question with the research I have done so far.

There is a package called [terraform-config-inspect](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect@v0.0.0-20210318070130-9a80970d6b34/tfconfig#Module)  however it doesn't support parsing the module arguments at the moment.

I have also looked at the [hclv2](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl)  ( as thats what Terraform uses ) from 0.13 and going forward, however I am not able to find any sort of function or method to parse the terraform files,just like it used to support in hclv1.

Thanks

Comment: As of Terraform 0.13, it is using github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2 which has different syntax.

Comment: I have looked at the hcl v2 when debugging this issue, however I am not able to find any sort of method/function in the package that can help me parse the module arguments. I have also looked at the [terraform-config-inspect](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect@v0.0.0-20210318070130-9a80970d6b34/tfconfig#Module) but it doesn't support parsing the module arguments either. Thanks.

Comment: Because of the way HCLv2 TF syntax works, you likely must use the `Parse` function to generate an AST and visit each node, rather than attempting to just `Unmarshal` it. There is nothing in HCL to help you handle the module arguments because they aren't strictly a part of HCL; all HCL knows is "this is a reference to something", it's up to the consumer to know what to do with it. You might take a look at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/lang and https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config

Comment: @Adrian, I have looked at pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config package and was able to parse my terraform config with [LoadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/config#LoadFile) method. Terraform has stopped supporting the LoadFile function from 0.14 and on wards. So I think I will pin my go.mod file to fetch the older version of the package. ( I am not sure if there are any downsides of using older version of package , since I am only going to use it just for parsing the arguments and nothing else ). Thank You !